# Unpredictable behavior of a function

Tags: plotting, numerics, discontinuity

The Hermitian matrix `mat` is used to construct a function `fun[x, y, z]` as follows:

```
  mat = {{1/2 + (Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z])/(
     8 x^2 - 2 Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]), (
    2 I x Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]^2)/(
    4 x^2 - Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z])}, {(
    2 I x Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]^2)/(-4 x^2 + 
     Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]), 
    1/2 (1 + (
       Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z])/(-4 x^2 + 
        Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]))}};


t1 = D[mat, x]; t2 = mat.t1;

fun[x_, z_] = Tr[t1.t1] + (1/Det[mat]) Tr[t2.t2];
```

Here, $0<x<0.5$, $z\ge0$. The problem is that `fun[x,z]` starts getting weird after some value of z, however it is expected to show smooth behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is numerically unstable. Luckily, [simplifying it](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) gives better results:

```
fun[x_, z_] = Tr[t1 . t1] + (1/Det[mat]) Tr[t2 . t2] // FullSimplify;

Plot[Re[fun[0.3, z]], {z, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Compare with the un-simplified original expression:

[image]

### Update

For even larger values of $z$, an asymptotic expansion can help. It's a bit tricky in this case because of the exponential behavior, so a regular series expansion won't do.

The dominant term for large $z$ is

```
f1[x_, z_] = Assuming[-1/2 < x < 1/2,
  Asymptotic[fun[x, z], z -> ∞]]
(*    4/(1-4*x^2)    *)
```

Adding the next correction term,

```
f2[x_, z_] = f1[x, z] + Assuming[-1/2 < x < 1/2,
  Asymptotic[fun[x, z] - f1[x, z], z -> ∞]]
(*    4/(1-4*x^2) - 32*Exp[-Sqrt[1-4*x^2]*z/2]*x^2*z/Sqrt[1-4*x^2]    *)
```

For large $z$ this function $f_2(x,z)$ gives an excellent approximation if $x$ is not too close to $\pm\frac12$.

More systematically, let's set $a=\exp(z\sqrt{\frac14-x^2})$ and series-expand around $a=\infty$:

```
Assuming[a > 0, 
  Series[fun[x, Log[a]/Sqrt[1/4-x^2]], {a, ∞, 2}] // FullSimplify]
```

$$
-\frac{4}{4 x^2-1}+\frac{16 \left(4 x^2 \log (a)-8 x^2+1\right)}{a \left(4 x^2-1\right)}+\frac{16 \left(-4 x^2 \log ^2(a)+64 x^4 \log (a)-112 x^4+24 x^2-1\right)}{a^2 \left(4
   x^2-1\right)}+O\left(a^{-3}\right)
$$
This approximation should give very good results for large $z$, specifically for large $\log(a)=z\sqrt{\frac14-x^2}$.

Comment: +1 The original expression works by using sufficiently high arbitrary-precision, e.g., `Plot[Re[fun[0.3`50, z]], {z, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotPoints -> 75]`. The simplification obviates the need for the high precision.

Comment: @BobHanlon using higher working precision in the face of numerical instability was the first thing we learned NOT to do in numerical analysis lectures. There's almost always a better way.

Comment: I agree, but note that you said "luckily"; for functions that do not simplify, high precision may be needed.

Comment: Thanks Roman. However, there is a problem! The function is showing an unexpected behavior in the range (roughly)  z: 1000 - 2000.

Comment: @Mike please see update. For $z=1000$ and above the exponential correction term is extremely small unless $x$ is close to $\pm\frac12$.

Comment: By the way for $x=1/2$, the function is $\frac{z^4 \left(z^2+36\right)}{9 \left(z^2+8\right)^2}$, which cannot be plotted for the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to refactor `fun[]` (the strategy is similar to how we teach computing limits at infinity: divide by the highest-order growth term):

```
mat = {{1/2 + (Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]) /
         (8 x^2 - 2 Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]),
        (2 I x Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]^2) / 
         (4 x^2 - Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z])},
       {(2 I x Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]^2)/
         (-4 x^2 + Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]), 
        1/2 (1 + (Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z])/
         (-4 x^2 + Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]))}
       } /. {
     Cosh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z] -> c, 
     Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z] -> s,
     Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z] -> c^2 + s^2, 
     Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z] -> 2 c s} /.
   s^2 -> c^2 - 1;

t1 = D[mat, x]; t2 = mat . t1;

ClearAll[fun];
funexpr = Tr[t1 . t1] + (1/Det[mat]) Tr[t2 . t2] // 
    Factor // 
   # /. s^2 -> c^2 - 1 /. c -> 1/c & // 
  Simplify
fun[x0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{x = x0, z = z0, c = 1/Cosh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x0^2] z0], s(*=
    Sinh[1/4 Sqrt[1-4 x0^2] z0]*)}, funexpr];

(*  funexpr: c == 1/Cosh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] z]
  (16 (-1 +   c^2) ( 1 + c^2 (-1 + 4 x^2))  ) /
    ( (-1 + 4 x^2) (-2 + c^2 ( 1 + 4 x^2))^2)
*)

Plot[Re[fun[0.3, z]], {z, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

There is a hard limit at machine precision, but it turns out not to be significant for `fun[]`.  The input to `Cosh` needs to be under around `700`. There would be a similar limit if `Cosh` were rewritten in terms of `Exp`.  This limit applies to any expression used for `fun[x, z]` that is in terms of `Cosh[]`.  For `z` at `x == 0.3`, the value of `z` can go up to around `3500`.  For values above this limit, `c` (or `c^2`) underflows to `0.`, but that does not introduce a significant error in the value of `fun[0.3, z]`.

```
Cosh[u] == $MaxMachineNumber // NSolve
```

> ```
> (*  {{u -> -710.476}, {u -> 710.476}}  *)
> ```

```
Cosh[1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 (0.3)^2] z] == $MaxMachineNumber // NSolve
```

> ```
> (*  {{z -> -3552.38}, {z -> 3552.38}}  *)
> ```

The following shows the precision loss for `x = 0.3` as a function of `z`. It's very good:

```
Plot[1000 - Precision@fun[0.3`1000, SetPrecision[z, 1000]],
 {z, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

The OP's original expression for `fun` loses about 35 digits of precision for each increase of `100` in the value of `z`, which is an extremely high rate:

> [image]